# Java on VSCode Extension Pack for Java can't detect jdk

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, settings, vscode-extensions, corretto

I am trying to run java on vscode however the 'Extension Pack for Java' keeps asking me to redownload the jdk. I am able to run java on intellij and have been using that but since I use vscode for everything else I would like to get it to work on my main editor.

Here are the settings related to java

```html
"java.help.firstView": "gettingStarted",
    "java.home":"/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/amazon-corretto-17.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java",
    "java.jdt.ls.java.home": "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/amazon-corretto-17.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java",
    "java.configuration.runtimes": [
  {
    "name": "JavaSE-17",
    "path": "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/microsoft-17.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java",
  },
  {
    "name": "JavaSE-17",
    "path": "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/temurin-17.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java",
  },
  {
    "name": "JavaSE-17",
    "path": "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/amazon-corretto-17.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java",
    "default": true
  },
],
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bfyGS.png)

*Error*
The java.home variable defined in Visual Studio Code settings points to a missing or inaccessible folder (/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-17.jdk/Contents/Home)

any ideas?

All other languages I use work fine, it just seems to be java.

Answer (score 1):

Assume you are using the latest Java extensions, here are some suggestions:

1. `java.home` has been deprecated, please don't use it and use `java.jdt.ls.java.home` instead
2. The latest Java extension already embeds a jre 17, you can find it in `$home/.vscode/extensions/redhat.java-1.x.0/jre`. Ideally there is no need to specify `java.jdt.ls.java.home`, unless your platform is not covered.
3. If your platform is not covered, then you need to manually set `java.jdt.ls.java.home`, which should point to the home path of your JDK installation. So please update it to `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/amazon-corretto-17.jdk/Contents/Home`.
4. `java.configuration.runtimes` is used to map different JDK versions to their installation path. Please make sure each version only appear once in this setting.

Comment: Sorry, where is `java.jdt.ls.java.home`?  When I go into Settings I see a UI and nothing matches when I search for this.

Answer (score 0):

JVM cant be found if it is installed in a directory owned by root (like /usr/lib/jvm), install the VM in a directory in your own home folder, that worked for me.