# VS code & java: This setting is deprecated, please use 'java.jdt.ls.java.home' instead

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

I faced this error when I was trying to set up Java in my vs code. In my settings.json:

```
"java.home": "C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk-17.0.22"
```

but the error says This setting is deprecated, please use 'java.jdt.ls.java.home' instead.
What is wrong here?

Comment: you must use `java.jdt.ls.java.home` instead of `java.home` since its deprecated this setting might be removed in later version of VS Code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What is wrong here?

You are using a setting name that has been deprecated.  This setting is still probably still going to work ... for now ... but it is likely that it will stop working completely in a future release.

So what you need to do is to **change** your "settings.xml" to use "java.jdt.ls.java.home" as the property name instead of "java.home". It would be advisable to do this as soon as practical.

---

Note that there is more information on the VSCode for Java settings [here](https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-java).  The current version of the page says this:

> `java.home` : **Deprecated, please use 'java.jdt.ls.java.home' instead.** Absolute path to JDK home folder used to launch the Java Language Server. Requires VS Code restart.

---

However, if your real problem is that VSCode is telling you that your version of the Java JDK is incompatible and you need to download a new one,  first read [`https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71042056/`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71042056/).  Downloading a new JDK (as suggested by VSCode) may not be the best solution.